# resetting a shape node when duplicating a geo object in maya

Tags: python, maya

I would love to duplicate a polycube using Python and by doing that resetting the shapeNode of the object to 0 (origin object) so that it can be used as a baseShape for corrective Blendshapes. My code works when doing the manual steps in Maya but not when I script it in Python:

```
selection = cmds.ls(selection=True)

for items in selection:
    cmds.setAttr ('%s.intermediateObject'%(items), 1)
    cmds.makeIdentity(items, apply=True, t=1, r=1, s=1, n=0, pn=1)
    cmds.delete(items, constructionHistory=True)
    cmds.setAttr ('%s.intermediateObject'%(items), 0)
```

Comment: Resetting? Freezing does not reset anything it moves all points. What does your code have to do with duplicating or polycubes? What are your manual steps?